# android | Using Bottom navigation and Navigation view in the same activity leads to App Crash with Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT)

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, navigationview

my app gets crash only if running on **Android N** phone. Below is the code for adding listeners to both the navigations.

in case you need more code to understand the error, pls let me know.

Comment: pls share crash log

Comment: thanks @Manish but the issue is resolved.